# Is it possible to send a request to django rest api to run a script?

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

I installed Django and Django Rest Api. I want to send some data to rest api. Rest api will take the data and run a script with this data and get a result. Then send this result back to me.
There won't be database usage.

Like this, request : http://testerapi.com:8000/search?q=title:xfaster564CertVal9body:A%22&fl=id
Response : {validation : true}

Is it possible?

Comment: do you want to get the script from request or only certain parameters?

Comment: Requester will send data to api. Api will give data to script on server. Script will take data and produce new data and send it back to api. Api will send new data back to requester.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible ! But i will try to respond with **api function based view**.

Let's suppose that our worker function to call when call the API (`GET` or `POST`) is in the `utilities.py` file, the `models.py`,  `serializers.py` and `views.py`.

**utilities.py**

```
def my_worker(a, b=0, c=0):
    # do something with a, b, c
    return a + b + c > 10
```

**models.py**

```
from datetime import datetime
class User(object):
    def __init__(self, email, name, created = None):
        self.email = email
        self.name = name
        self.created = created or datetime.now()
```

**serializers.py**
*I use simple Serializer but **ModelSerializer** is better i think*

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    # initialize fields
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length = 200)
    created = serializers.DateTimeField()
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt # Allow request without csrf_token set
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

from .models import User
from .serializers import UserSerializer
# Import my_worker from .utilities
from .utilities import my_worker

@csrf_exempt
@api_view('GET')  # Only get request is allowed
def user_worker(request, a, b, c):
    """
    Do something with 
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        # Do some stuff
        users = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
        # Call the utilities script here
        result = my_worker(a, b, c)
        if result:  # a+b+c > 10
            return JsonResponse({"validation": "true"}, safe=False)
        else:
            return JsonResponse({"validation": "false"}, safe=False)
```

Note that i dont use *the UserSerializer* but show it at example.
You can then execute a more complex function (here the `my_worker`).
Adapt it according to your needs.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks ALOT! That was the thing i was looking for. Thanks!